# Append to XML file using XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using `XmlDocument` and `XmlWriter` to append XML into an existing file, but my attempt below is throwing an exception that I don't understand

> This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node.

```
//Append to xml file

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"c:\\test.xml");
using (XmlWriter xmlWrite = doc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
{
    xmlWrite.WriteStartElement("image name=",Name);
    xmlWrite.WriteElementString("width", widthValue[1]);
    xmlWrite.WriteElementString("Height", heightValue[1]);
    xmlWrite.WriteElementString("file-size", FileSizeValue[1]);
    xmlWrite.WriteElementString("file-format", FileFormatValue[1]);
    xmlWrite.WriteElementString("resolution", ResolutionValue[1]);
    xmlWrite.Close();
}
```

here is my sample test.xml

```
<job-metadata>
    <slug>730s_Sales/CupWinner_0111</slug>
    <locations>Africa</locations>
    <primary-location>Africa</primary-location>
    <reporter>Leigh Sales</reporter>
    <genre>Current</genre>
    <copyright>CBS</copyright>
    <autopublish>true</autopublish> 
</job-metadata>
```

Am trying to append in the xml like below

```
<job-metadata>
    <slug>730s_Sales/CupWinner_0111</slug>
    <locations>Africa</locations>
    <primary-location>Africa</primary-location>
    <reporter>Leigh Sales</reporter>
    <genre>Current</genre>
    <copyright>CBS</copyright>
    <autopublish>true</autopublish> 
    <image name="557684_20111101-730s_SalesCupWinner_0111_80x60.jpg">
        <width>80</width>
        <height>60</height>
        <file-size>7045</file-size>
        <file-format>JPEG Baseline</file-format>
        <resolution>72</resolution>
        <custom-name>newsthumbnail</custom-name>
    </image>
</job-metadata>
```

Comment: is it helpful?.................

Comment: Absolutely,thanks a lot for eg, i haven't modify yet,am gonna start writing one now. i will post the code back here. Thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To play with the XML data if you are using .net version 3.5 its better to user [**LINQ to XML**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24376/LINQ-to-XML

**or**

[Manipulate XML data with XPath and XmlDocument (C#)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C)

**OR**

Article : [How to Append to a Large XML File](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15278/How-to-Append-to-a-Large-XML-File)

I thnik you need to append node to your xmldocuemnt like this

```
//add to elements collection
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(node);
```

You need to do something like this

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc=new XmlDocument();

xmlDoc.Load("F:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/Account.xml");

XmlElement subRoot=xmlDoc.CreateElement("User");
//UserName
XmlElement appendedElementUsername=xmlDoc.CreateElement("UserName");
XmlText xmlTextUserName=xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(txtUsrName.Text.Trim());
appendedElementUsername.AppendChild(xmlTextUserName);
subRoot.AppendChild(appendedElementUsername);
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(subRoot);
//Email

XmlElement appendedElementEmail=xmlDoc.CreateElement("Email");
XmlText xmlTextEmail=xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(txtEmail.Text.Trim());
appendedElementEmail.AppendChild(xmlTextEmail);
subRoot.AppendChild(appendedElementEmail);
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(subRoot);

xmlDoc.Save("F:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/Account.xml");if(!File.Exists("F:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/Account.xml"))
{

XmlTextWriter textWritter=new XmlTextWriter("F:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/Account.xml", null); 
textWritter.WriteStartDocument();
textWritter.WriteStartElement("USERS");
textWritter.WriteEndElement();

textWritter.Close();
}



XmlDocument xmlDoc=new XmlDocument();

xmlDoc.Load("F:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/Account.xml");

XmlElement subRoot=xmlDoc.CreateElement("User");
//UserName
XmlElement appendedElementUsername=xmlDoc.CreateElement("UserName");
XmlText xmlTextUserName=xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(txtUsrName.Text.Trim());
appendedElementUsername.AppendChild(xmlTextUserName);
subRoot.AppendChild(appendedElementUsername);
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(subRoot);
//Email

XmlElement appendedElementEmail=xmlDoc.CreateElement("Email");
XmlText xmlTextEmail=xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(txtEmail.Text.Trim());
appendedElementEmail.AppendChild(xmlTextEmail);
subRoot.AppendChild(appendedElementEmail);
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(subRoot);

xmlDoc.Save("F:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/Account.xml");
```

The result'll be like that:

```
</USERS>
<User>
<UserName>Buggaya</UserName> 

<Email>Buggaya@gmail.com</Email> 
</User>
</USERS>
```

orignal post : [Append in xml document](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/53292)