# How to add data to an existing xml file in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using this c# code to write data to xml file:

```
Employee[] employees = new Employee[2];
employees[0] = new Employee(1, "David", "Smith", 10000);
employees[1] = new Employee(12, "Cecil", "Walker", 120000);

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("employees.xml"))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("Employees");

    foreach (Employee employee in employees)
    {
    writer.WriteStartElement("Employee");

    writer.WriteElementString("ID", employee.Id.ToString());
    writer.WriteElementString("FirstName", employee.FirstName);
    writer.WriteElementString("LastName", employee.LastName);
    writer.WriteElementString("Salary", employee.Salary.ToString());

    writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
}
```

Now suppose I restart my application and I want to add new data to the xml file without losing the existed data, using the same way will overwrite the data on my xml file, I tried to figure out how to do that and I searched for a similar example but I couldn't come to anything , any ideas ??

Comment: A simple way would be to read the file into memory, modify it there, and overwrite the file.

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188574/append-xml-file-using-xmlwriter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you should look at some examples using datasets and xml:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13854/Using-XML-as-Database-with-Dataset

or use System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer, when you dont't have amount of records.

Example using XmlDocument

```
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.Load("employees.xml");
XmlNode nl = xd.SelectSingleNode("//Employees");
XmlDocument xd2 = new XmlDocument();
xd2.LoadXml("<Employee><ID>20</ID><FirstName>Clair</FirstName><LastName>Doner</LastName><Salary>13000</Salary></Employee>");
XmlNode n = xd.ImportNode(xd2.FirstChild,true);
nl.AppendChild(n);
xd.Save(Console.Out);
```

Comment: using the code above and replacing the last line   xd.Save("employees.xml"); is what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using an xml writer for small amounts of data is awkward. You would be better of using an `XDocument` that you either initialize from scratch for the first run, or read from an existing file in subsequent runs.

Using `XDocument` you can manipulate the XML with `XElement` and `XAttribute` instances and then write the entire thing out to a file when you want to persist it.

Comment: Is there any example ? I'm not sure how deal with this,for example can I load the xml file using XDocument then append new element using XElement ?